# How to label arrows in tikz-cd diagrams with matrices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) for some commutative diagrams, but if I try to label an arrow with a matrix, `&` appears to be "undefined control sequence". So all the entries in a row get concatenated, and it looks like a column vector. The following is a (minimal) working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} } & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because the `tikz-cd` environment is a wrapper around a TikZ matrix and in a TikZ matrix then `&` doesn't mean what it usually means.  Inside a TikZ matrix then `&` is a command which does a fair bit extra than the usual "hop to the next cell".  However, inside an AMS matrix, you want it to be just the "hop to the next cell" that it usually is.  So the two occurrences of `&` in your code have different meanings but you are using the same symbol for them.  There are a variety of ways to fix this:

1. Keep the normal meaning of `&` so that it works inside the AMS matrix, in which case you need to use something else for the TikZ matrix.  Fortunately, TikZ provides a way to do this: you write `[ampersand replacement=\&]` (or whatever) after the `\begin{tikzcd}` and then use `\&` (or whatever) for the TikZ cell separator.
2. Keep TikZ's meaning of `&` so that it works for the TikZ matrix, in which case you need to use something else for the AMS matrix.  This is also quite straightforward.  You put `\let\amsamp=&` in your preamble and then use `\amsamp` in your code (unfortunately, it would appear that `\&` can't be used here).
3. Rejig AMS's matrix environment to reset `&` to its usual meaning whilst inside its environs.  This isn't quite as easy as it looks due to the fact that when the environment is read then the catcode of `&` is already frozen (as it is in the argument to a macro, in this case `\arrow`).  So we have to do a bit of `\begingroup ... \endgroup` trickery when defining the new type of matrix environment.  (Obviously, to do this right one should just redefine the basic AMS matrix environment that all the others are built on top of).  Note that this also works outside `tikzcd` environments because what it actually does is say "If `&` is a command, let it be what `&` usually is." (okay, it's *slightly* more complicated but that'll do for now) and in the normal circumstances `&` isn't a command so this is (almost) a NO-OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81618/86}
\let\amsamp=&

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begingroup
\catcode`\&=13
\gdef\pampmatrix{%
  \begingroup
  \let&=\amsamp
  \begin{pmatrix}%
}
\gdef\endpampmatrix{\end{pmatrix}\endgroup}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\]

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow{r}{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} } \& B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \amsamp 0 \\ 0 \amsamp 1 \end{pmatrix}
} & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{ \begin{pampmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pampmatrix} } & B
\end{tikzcd}

\[
  \begin{pampmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
  \end{pampmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: ampersands and matrices with TikZ and AMS]

---

As a postscript (or PDF), I would like to point out that this is a lovely example of the distinction between *fudge*, *Finagle*, and *diddle* factors as explained in [an article](http://cd.textfiles.com/hackchronii/RADIO1/FINAGLE.TXT) in *THE IRE STUDENT QUARTERLY*, SEPTEMBER 1958 (also reproduced in the wonderful book *A Random Walk in Science*, or it might be in *More Random Walks in Science*).  The following is the relevant part:

> However, John W. Campbell feels there is a different basic structure 
>   behind the Finagle, fudge and diddle factors.  The Finagle factor, 
>   he claims, is characterized by changing the universe to fit an 
>   equation.  The fudge factor, on the other hand, changes the equation 
>   to fit the universe.  And finally, the diddle factor changes things 
>   so that the universe and the equation appear to fit, without making 
>   any real change in either.
>
> For example, the planet Uranus was introduced to the universe when 
>   Newtonian laws couldn't be to match known planetary motions.  This 
>   is a beautiful example of the application of the Finagle factor.
>
> Einstein's work leading to relativity was strongly influenced by the 
>   observed facts about the orbit of Mercury.  Obviously a fudge factor 
>   was introduced.
>
> The photographer's use of a "soft-focus" lens when taking portraits 
>   of women over 35 is an example of the diddle factor.  By blurring 
>   the results, photographs are made to appear to match the facts in a 
>   far more satisfactory manner.

Thus the first solution, which changes TikZ to fit AMS, is clearly an application of the Finagle factor.  The second, which changes AMS to fit TikZ, is obviously a fudge.  The last, in which everything suddenly appears to work with no outward change, is a definite diddle.

Comment: Your first solution, redefining `&` for TikZ-cd, doesn't seem to work for the "newer" notation for arrows `\arrow[direction, options, "label"]` (I'm guessing that it's newer and preferred notation; it's used in the 2014 TikZ manual). Anyways, the compiler complains if there's an `&` inside of a matrix environment in the `"label"` saying `Argument of \tikzcd@@arrow has an extra }.`. You wouldn't happen to know what's causing this, or how adapt your solution to fix this error, would you?

Comment: @MikePierce I'm sorry, I don't actually use `tikz-cd` so I don't know anything about any changes in notation.  This answer (now over 5yrs old) was - I think - build on my knowledge of the tikz matrix command.  Your example appears to use the `quotes` library and so it may be an issue with that.  At a complete guess, I'd try putting a few things in braces to see if that helps.

Comment: The following taken from "{tikzcd}" also does the job: `\def\temp{&} \catcode\`&=\active \let&=\temp` Note that there was a typo in the reference declaring the catcode with `‘` instead of `\``. Do you know wether that "solution" is fine or what bad could happen? Thanks, A.