# labeling diagrams with matrices

Tags: matrices, xy-pic

I it possible to label an arrow with a matrix in Xy-pic?  In the following diagram I want to label the arrows with 2x2 matrices to represent linear maps between vector spaces, in the place of a,b and c.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
{\bullet}^{V_1}\ar[r]^a &{\bullet}^{V_2}\ar[d]^b
\\&{\bullet}^{V_3}\ar[ul]^c
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

It is for a diagram of a quiver representation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

You could just substitute the `a`, `b`, `c` for the matrix or whatever you want in brackets (I've added the `-` before so that the label is aligned in the middle of the arrow, not the middle of the row/column). Here's an example:

```
\begin{equation*} 
    \xymatrix @R=2cm @C=2cm { 
    {\bullet}^{V_1} \ar[r]^-{a = \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4
    \end{pmatrix}} & {\bullet}^{V_2} \ar[d]^-{b = \begin{pmatrix}
        b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4
    \end{pmatrix}} \\
    & {\bullet}^{V_3} \ar[ul]^-{c = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_1 & c_2 \\ c_3 & c_4
    \end{pmatrix}} 
    }
\end{equation*}
```

And may be you would like to write into an `smallmatrix`, which could be enough for your needs:

```
\begin{equation*} 
    \xymatrix @R=2cm @C=2cm { 
    {\bullet}^{V_1} \ar[r]^-{a = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)} & {\bullet}^{V_2} \ar[d]^-{b = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
        b_1 & b_2 \\ b_3 & b_4
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)} \\
    & {\bullet}^{V_3} \ar[ul]^-{c = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
        c_1 & c_2 \\ c_3 & c_4
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)} 
    }
\end{equation*}
```

The `@R=X` and the `@C=Y` in the `xymatrix` command gives you the chance to change row and column separation.

There is a package `tikz-cd` ([here](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) is the manual at CTAN) which, in my opinion, gives better quality and the language used is easier to understand (i.e. `\arrow[hookrightarrow]{rr}{a}` instead of the xymatrix `\ar@{^{(}->}[rr]^-{a}`; or `\rar{a}` instead of `\ar[r]^-{a}`). But, in this concrete case there is a problem: `tikz-cd` causes problems if you want to label an arrow with a matrix ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81618/how-to-label-arrows-in-tikz-cd-diagrams-with-matrices) is a better explanation). That's why I don't include an example here.

Comment: Probably `smallmatrix` is the best choice. I'd say `\xymatrix @R+1pc @C+1pc{...}` rather than setting explicit dimensions (this adds 12pt to both the intercolumn and interrow spaces).

Comment: I thought saying it in `cm` would be more explicit and easy to understand. But that's a good tip. Anyway, to the OP @nick, may be you would like to look for the `tikz-cd`package, which is similar and, in my opinion, easier to understand.

Comment: Why don't you give also a solution based on `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Trying to make it I discover that `tikz-cd` doesn't recognize matrixes in the labels of the arrows, I get an error. It only separates the rows and not the columns (as a `substack`)! I don't know. ... And here's the answer [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81618/how-to-label-arrows-in-tikz-cd-diagrams-with-matrices). In this case it wouldn't clarify anything for de OP I think.